# Consulta JQuery-Ajax Laravel 5.5

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

> Não consigo fazer a consulta ajax no Laravel5.5.

### Form de consulta:

```
<form action="ConsultaEmpresa" method="get" name="FormConsultaEmpresa" id="FormConsultaEmpresa">
          {{ csrf_field() }}

   <input type="date" style="width: 30%;" class="form-control" name="Data_Inicial" id="Data_Inicial">

   <button class="btn btn-success" style="margin-left: 10px;" id="Consulta_Empresa" type="submit">Pesquisar</button>

</form>
```

## Consulta JS( Ajax para a consulta):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($)  {
    $("#FormConsultaEmpresa").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: "get",
            url: "/ConsultaEmpresa/ " + $('#Data_Inicial').attr("value"),
            dataType: 'json',
            headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') },
            data : $(this).serialize(),
            success: function (Consulta) {
                    Consulta.responseJSON;
                    console.log(Consulta);
            },complete() {
                    console.log("complete");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

### Controller que retorna a consulta Ajax

```
public function ConsultaAjax(Request $Data_Inicial)
    {
        /*
        $date = explode("/", $Data_Inicial);

        $dateBanco = $date[2]."/" . $date[1] . "/" . $date[0];*/

        $Consulta = DB::table('empresas')->where([ ['Empresa_Dtinicioacesso', '=', $dateBanco] ])->get();        

        return Response::json($Consulta);
    }
```

### Rota da minha consulta

```
Route::get('/ConsultaEmpresa/{Data_Inicial}', ['uses' => 'EmpresaController@ConsultaAjax']);
```

Aparece essa mensagem no log(Inserir elemento) quando termina a requisição.

> XHR finished loading: POST
>   "http://127.0.0.1:8000/ConsultaEmpresa/%20undefined"

Comment: ok vou tentar man

Comment: Pegou man, mas agora ta assim http://127.0.0.1:8000/ConsultaEmpresa/%201996-10-23

Comment: na frente da minha rota ta com esse " %20 " toda vez que manda uma requisição

Comment: Tira o espaço: `"/ConsultaEmpresa/ "`

Comment: vlw man ajudou muito, God demais

Comment: Tira uma duvida se eu quiser passar dois parâmetros na minha rota ajax como faço ? que irá vim do meu form

Comment: Vc diz aqui? `Route::post('/ConsultaEmpresa/{Data_Inicial}'`

Comment: Também man tanto na rota quanto no ajax, tipo data inicial e data final.

Comment: No Ajax vc pode fazer algo assim: `url: "/ConsultaEmpresa/ " + $('#Data_Inicial').val()+$('#Data_Final').val()`, mas as duas datas ficarão juntas... tem que ver como vc quer enviar as duas coisas, como elas ficarão separadas na URL.

Comment: entendi man, já sei como passar os dois na URL

Comment: Já na rota eu não entendo de Laravel, mas deve ser algo simples tb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está tentando pegar o valor de forma errada: `$('#Data_Inicial').attr("value")`.

Utilize `$('#Data_Inicial').val()` para pegar o valor do campo, já que ele não possui o atributo `value` explícito.

Ficaria assim:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($)  {
    $("#FormConsultaEmpresa").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "/ConsultaEmpresa/" + $('#Data_Inicial').val(),
            dataType: 'json',
            headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') },
            data : $(this).serialize(),
            success: function (Consulta) {
                    Consulta.responseJSON;
                    console.log(Consulta);
            },complete() {
                    console.log("complete");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

> Retire também esse espaço em branco após a última barra em
>   `"/ConsultaEmpresa/ "`. Parece estar incorreto também.

Comment: vlw man <3 tamo junto